# SQL add select query to another select query as a new column

Tags: sql, join

I have two SQL select query. I want to add second select results to first query as a new column. How can I do?

My queries - first query:

```
SELECT 
    [Value], ColumnIndex, RowIndex + 1 AS RowIndex,
    Axis, SegmentationModuleType, ModuleType, VersionId, IsTotalValue FROM 
    FinalWeightCalculation
WHERE 
    Axis IS NULL
    AND IsTotalValue = 1 
    AND SegmentationModuleType = 'Choosing' 
    AND ModuleType = 'TSY02' 
    AND VersionId = 299 
    AND AccountGuid = 'f069b6d7-b2d1-4f36-b6a4-9d830f35de73' 
ORDER BY
    RowIndex
```

Second query:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo) as RowIndex, Name from Criteria where VersionId = 299 order by OrderNo
```

[image]

Comment: Which columns provide the relationship between the two result sets?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen By updating the second query as follows, we can say that there is a relationship. I have updated the screenshot and second query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join on the row number:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    -- your first query
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo) rn
    FROM Criteria 
    WHERE VersionId = 299 
)

SELECT t1.*, t2.Name
FROM cte1 t1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t2.rn = t1.RowIndex
ORDER BY t1.RowIndex;
```